# Join a table with itself

Tags: postgresql

I have a big table (which i created from 3 small tables) which looks like this

```
Acquisition | device | user_id | user_name
------------|--------|---------|----------
null        |   1    |    1    |   John
3           |   2    |    1    |   John
4           |   4    |    3    |   Mary
null        |   5    |    4    |   Snow
```

I want to know wich user have not made any  acquisition yet, for this example (4, Snow) would be the answer, as John has made the Acquisition 3.

I made this query

```
select user_id, user_name 
from adquisicion_dispositivo
where acquisition is null and
user_id not in
(select user_id from adquisicion_dispositivo where
acquisition is not null);
```

But it takes too long (half hour and going ~1 million rows).
This table does not have any id's.

this is the schema of the table

```
  Columna      |          Tipo          | Modificadores
-------------------+------------------------+---------------
id_adquisicion    | integer                |
id_articulo       | integer                |
id_dispositivo    | integer                |
fecha_adquisicion | date                   |
id_usuario        | integer                |
version_android   | character varying(100) |
nombre_usuario    | character varying(100) |
fecha_nacimiento  | date                   |
sexo              | character varying(20)  |
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to DBA.SE. You need to `CREATE INDEX ON adquisicion_dispositivo (acquisition, user_id)` to speed up your query (which, apart from that, looks ok).

Comment: Can you paste the result of `\d adquisicion_dispositivo`

Comment: Always show your DDL code--it includes information that is important. Here, any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On large tables you may be able to speed it up.

```
SELECT user_id, user_name 
FROM adquisicion_dispositivo AS a1
WHERE acquisition IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM adquisicion_dispositivo AS a2
  WHERE acquisition IS NOT NULL
  AND a1.user_id = a2.user_id
);
```

You need to show your table with `\d adquisicion_dispositivo`. You may need an index, @joanolo's suggestion is good switch the order though I would switch the order,

```
CREATE INDEX ON adquisicion_dispositivo (user_id, acquisition);
```

Comment: Your query is like 100 times faster than mine, thank you, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
select user_id, user_name 
from adquisicion_dispositivo 
group by user_id, user_name 
having count( Acquisition ) = 0
```

count( Acquisition ) does not count rows where Acquisition is null, so the query return all users that do not have any acquisitions. The query does a single scan of the table so it may (or may not) be faster than a self join, you need to test that out with realistic data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this query:

```
select user_id
from adquisicion_dispositivo
group by user_id
having min(acquisition) is null ;
```